# Get the directory of a found file - Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, unix

I'm trying to find the path of my Laravel project

I did this

```
sudo find / -name artisan
```

I got this

```
/home/forge/john/artisan
```

I only want this part

```
/home/forge/john/
```

I've tried this

```
sudo find / -name artisan | pwd;
```

I got

```
/root
```

I only want the path of that found file which is `/home/forge/john/`

Can someone give a little hints here ?

---

I've tried

```
project_path=$("dirname `sudo find / -name artisan`")
echo "$project_path"
```

I kept getting

```
bash: line 103: dirname /home/forge/john/artisan: No such file or directory                     

/root
```

Comment: I would encourage you to use the answer from the duplicate, since all the suggestions here are suboptimal in one way or another (e.g. none work for the path `/home/me/bipartisan propaganda/mydir/artisan`)

Comment: seem like the command work by itself, but when store into `variable` it started behave weird.  `project_path=$("dirname `sudo find / -name artisan`") `

Comment: The command ``"dirname `sudo find / -name artisan`"`` doesn't work by itself just like it doesn't work in your `$(..)` The command ``dirname `sudo find / -name artisan` `` (without double quotes) works in both, insofar as the command can be said to work

Comment: Are these 2 commands look clean to you ? I didn't get the result I wanted, and I have no idea why : https://i.imgur.com/PWNo1yu.png

Comment: No. They have the same problem with bad double quotes. The command should be `project_path=$(dirname "$(sudo find / -name artisan)")` with a comment "# TODO: Make this work if there are multiple or zero matches"

Comment: don't quote the command otherwise it thinks `dirname /home/forge/john/artisan` as one command you are trying to run not `dirname`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command [dirname](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname), which strips away the non-directory part of a path

To integrate it with the rest of your command, you can do this:

```
dirname `sudo find / -name artisan`
```

or

```
dirname $(sudo find / -name artisan)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion update my post, shall those commands work when run as a script ? Should I put a sleep in between ?

Comment: No sleep is  necessary, as the part in backticks or $() is executed first, to make it into a script, change 'artisan' to '$0', if the name of the file will be passed as its first argument

Comment: seem like the command work by itself, but when store into `variable` it started behave weird.  `project_path=$("dirname `sudo find / -name artisan`") `

Comment: I kept getting this error `-bash: dirname /home/forge/john/artisan: No such file or directory` : https://i.imgur.com/CSn6rsG.png

Comment: try to store that path into the variable, and go into that path, won't work, cuz that path now store wrong info.

Comment: That's because putting anything in a string "", doesn't execute it, instead it stores it, so you end up with "dirname" + `whatever the output of this command is`, so just say $(dirname `sudo find / -name artisan`)

Comment: Try that got this error : https://i.imgur.com/ySknjFp.png

Comment: @Mememyselfandaverycreepy 's command was supposed to read ``var=$(dirname `sudo find / -name artisan`) `` but StackOverflow ate the inner backticks. To write commands with embedded single backticks, use two backticks as delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` to handle the string that you get from `find`

```
sudo find / -name artisan | awk -F 'artisan' '{print $1}'
```

Comment: I think that, especially since a program already exsists to do it, bringing in another scripting environment (as much as I love awk), might be to much/unnecessary.

Comment: seem like the command work by itself, but when store into `variable` it started behave weird.  `project_path=$("dirname `sudo find / -name artisan`") `

Comment: I kept getting this error `-bash: dirname /home/forge/john/artisan: No such file or directory` : https://i.imgur.com/CSn6rsG.png

Comment: @kyo I think you are commenting on the wrong answer, since I didn't suggest you to use `dirname` but `awk` instead :)

Comment: So sorry, let me try your suggestion now

Answer (score 0):

some hints

```
dirname /home/forge/john/artisan
/home/forge/join

basename /home/forge/john/artisan
artisan
```

Comment: I kept getting this error `-bash: dirname /home/forge/john/artisan: No such file or directory` : https://i.imgur.com/CSn6rsG.png

Comment: the command should not be quoted. run `echo $("echo what")  echo $(echo "what")` you will see the difference.